# Get column with text datatype slow query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have the following table:

```
create table tbl_img
(
  id int,
  col_img text
);
```

I have stored image in the column `col_img`.

When I try to get data:

```
select t1.id,t1.col1,t2.col_img
from tbl_test t1
left join tbl_img t2 on t1.img_id = t2.id;
```

Taking more than 1 minute time to get data. If I remove `t2.col_img` from column list it will give result within milliseconds.

Is there any work around to improve performance?

Comment: Maybe find a way without using the join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `t2.col_img` from the `SELECT` list, PostgreSQL is smart enough to know that it can skip the left join, since `id` on `tbl_img` has a unique constraint.

With `t2.col_img`, PostgreSQL actually has to perform the join, so it is much more expensive.

There is little you can do to speed it up:

- increase `work_mem` in the hope to get a hash join (if you don't already have that)
- get faster storage or more RAM to cache data